# Hibernate LazyInitializationExceptioin in a "non-web" Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4 in a **console application** (i'm trying some functionalities of these frameworks and their integration).

How can I solve Hibernate `LazyInitializationExceptioin` in a *non-web-application*?

I've red about using `OpenSessionInViewFilter`, but none about applications that don't use servlets...
Which is the right way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before returning the instances loaded by hibernate to the view layer of your console application ,  always make sure that the entities that you need to display or access in the view layer are initialized .

You can force initialize an entities using the following methods:

1. [Hibernate.initialize()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29):

   For example , you have have to display all the  `orderDetail` for an `Order` in the view layer but your console application only load an `order` instance. Assume  `orderDetail` is lazy loaded , before returning the `order` to the  view layer , call  `Hibernate.initialize(order.getOrderDetail())`
2. Use the [fetch join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) to fetch the `orderDetail` along with the `order` which causes the returned `order` object have their `orderDetail` fully initialized :

   SELECT order  FROM Order order **join fetch** order.orderDetail

---

Update :

`fetch = FetchType.EAGER` on the  `@OneToMany` is the 3rd option. It will cause that if a `order` is loaded , its `orderDetail` will also be automatically loaded and initialized too .But this affects globally. We normally don't change the default lazy fetch plan of `@OneToMany` to eager fetching in mapping metadata unless it is absolutely sure to do it . Instead , we use the `fetch join` (option 2)  to override the default lazy fetch plan to be eagerly fetched  for a particualr use case.

Comment: i'd recommend the second approach.

Comment: Is it the same thing to set `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in `@OneToMany` annotation?